# Viewing a portion of a very large CSV file?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a ~1.0gb CSV file, and when trying to load it into Excel just to view, Excel crashes. I don't know the schema of the file, so it's difficult for me to load it into R or Python. The file contains restaurant reviews and has commas in it.

How can I open just a portion of the file (say, the first 100 rows, or 1.0mb's worth) in Windows Notepad or Excel?

Comment: One way would be to derive a copy with only the first 10 lines. In linux or osx one might call `head -100 FILENAME.csv > 100_LINES.csv` and then open the new file ... with python (Question is tagged with python) you might open the file and read only 100 lines print/write  them to a file and that would be it, that you open to investigate.

Comment: This is not really a Python question, I suggest you remove the tag :) there are operating system tools to do this which are far superior to coding this on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my version of excel the open dialogs do not seem to offer a "read only these many lines" option, only a start at line (used to skip headers I guess).

So if you have no head binary at hand on your platform, but python a simplistic working solution for your case should be (hard coded 100 lines aka rows):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

LINE_COUNT = 100


def main():
    """Do the thing."""
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit("Usage: InFIle OutHead100File")
    in_name, out_name = sys.argv[1:3]
    print("Simple head(100)[%s] -> %s ..." % (in_name, out_name))
    with open(in_name, 'rt') as f_in, open(out_name, 'wt') as f_out:
        for n in range(LINE_COUNT):
            f_out.write(f_in.readline())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and one would call the above code (assuming stored in script file `so_x_head_100.py` and given a file `huge.csv` should have first 100 rows copied to a file `100.csv`):

```
$ python2 ./so_x_head_100.py huge.csv 100.csv
Simple head(100)[huge.csv] -> 100.csv ...
```

And now in `100.csv`ther are the first 100 lines of `huge.csv`.

Comment: This is a memory-efficient code. I am using for files of size ~50GB, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do somewhat more selective fishing for particular rows, then the python `csv` module will allow you to read the csv file row by row into Python data structures. Consult the documentation.

This may be useful if just grabbing the first hundred lines reveals nothing about many of the columns because they are blank in all those rows. So you could easily write a program in Python to read as many rows as it takes to find and write out a few rows with non-blank data in particular columns. Likewise if you want to analyze a subset of the data matching particular criteria, you can read all the rows in and write only the interesting ones out for further analysis.

An alternative to csv is pandas. Bigger learning curve, but it is probably the right tool for analyzing big data. (1Gb is not very big these days).

Comment: I don't have admin rights on the computer I'm using, so unfortunately I've had a rough time installing any useful modules in Python, e.g. pandas and numpy.

Comment: Does the computer have `virtualenv` installed? If so just set up your own virtualenv and work in it, using pip to install just about anything Python that you need. (If it does not have virtualenv, complain! )

Comment: I already requested virtualenv... It's "on it's way" according to my supervisor. I should have it by the end of the week.. Trust me, I made it clear I NEEDED a virtualenv to actually do my job!!

Comment: Sounds like a place I once knew. I presume that the other approach (find an old PC that someone is throwing out, install Linux yourself) is also rendered impossible by the network and firewall people or regulations?

Comment: Yes, just about everything "roundabout" or third-party is strictly governed by the security division. I certainly don't have nearly the freedom I have on my personal machine :)